# How to insert data form into table when press a button?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

How to make Vuejs add in a table more than one data form when pressing a button? I can do it just with one form, I need to make it happen with input and select form and when I press a button to add it in a list. Thanks.

Here is an example:
http://embed.plnkr.co/aax7vC/

Comment: We can't help you unless you show us some code and what you have tried already.

Comment: Yes, sure. Here is an example: http://embed.plnkr.co/aax7vC/

Comment: So what is your question? You want to add a select box to your form?

Comment: I want to create a serie of forms, the person will write and click in button to add it in a table or list all the data forms in other page(if possible, can be on the same page). But I can only do this with a single form. Thanks for responding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your example, I'm assuming you want multiple fields to go into a list of elements. This means it's all about your data model. You must replicate the "table" structure that you want for 1 single element. So simply declare an object with those fields and do the data binding. Then when clicking "Add", simply add that object (assuming your array is of the same type).

```
app = new Vue({
  el: "#main",
  data: {
    users: [],
    newElement: {user:"",status:""}
  },
  methods: {
    addUser: function(){
      this.users.push({user:this.newElement.user,status:this.newElement.status});
      this.newElement = {user:"",status:""};
    },
    removeUser: function(item){
      this.users.splice(item,1);
    }
  }
});
```

Notice that the push replicates the structure, instead of just adding this.newElement. That will cause a reference relationship, and when you clear newElement it will be cleared in the array.
Then your HTML can be like this:

```html
      <input type="text" v-model="newElement.user">
      <select v-model="newElement.status"><option>Hired</option><option>Fired</option></select>
      <button v-on="click: addUser()" v-attr="disabled: newElement.user ===''">Add</button>
      <p v-if="users.length > 0">Click to remove</p>
      <ul>
        <li v-repeat="u : users" v-on="click: removeUser(u)">{{u.user}} {{u.status}}</li>
      </ul>
```

Comment: Omg, thank you so much. Works perfeclty. To add more, just follow the same way you do?

Comment: Yes, just add more properties and it should be OK

Comment: The local storage that was in the code stopped working, do you know why?

Comment: I removed it for clarity in my code. Simply put it back in the declaration of the data and call it at the end of the method addUser and removeUser to update on any data changes:
`data:
{
    users: fetchArray(...),
...
}
methods:
{
    addUsers:function()
    {
        ...
        saveArray(...);
    },
...
}`

Comment: Actually you already had a "watch", which might be better than calling it on every method that alters the array

Comment: Sorry, I couldn't do that.